# Remove settings on disable/uninstall

Tags: vscode-extensions

How do we remove some settings when extension is disabled/uninstalled?
There is a [uninstall hook](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/extension-manifest#extension-uninstall-hook) but it seems to be running outside of vscode environment and `vscode.workspace.getConfiguration()` is not available (at least in my tests by simply running the script with `npm run vscode:uninstall`)

The reason I need this, is because as a work around of a [bug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/201603) the extension *forcibly* adds some settings into global config.